# How to check if current request or route is part of Auth::routes() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to hide the sidebar in the default `app.blade.php` file without making a new layout file.

I am trying to add an if statement to hide the sidebar if the request or route is part of the ones created by `Auth::routes()`

I know I can list a bunch of `Request::is('login')` and `Request::is('register')` etc...

I was just wondering if there's a simple catch all to check if the request is any of the auth-related pages.

Thanks!

Comment: nope, not really ... potentially you could check the controller that is being used for the current route and see if it is in the `Auth` namespace but sounds like extra work

Comment: @lagbox yeah, that way I have it right now is having all three `(!Request::is('login') && !Request::is('register') && !Request::is('password/*'))` which isn't so bad. I was wondering if anyone know a catch-all way of doing this. Thanks!

Comment: btw you dont need to call `Request::is` so many times, it can take a variable amount of arguments of all the patterns you want to check `Request::is('login', 'register', 'password/*')` .. but I have another way you can do this actually, I will post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the Current route name falls within the desired list.

```
@if (in_array(request()->route()->getName(), ['login', 'register']))

// Request is in Auth Routes

@else

// Request not in Auth Routes

@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to get sneaky and use the `actions` array for a Route. When defining a group these attributes get merged in the with Route's attributes.

Setup a group with a `authroutes`(or any other name you would like) attribute:

```
Route::group(['authroutes' => true, ....], function () {
    Auth::routes(...);
});
```

In a view you can check the current route to see if it has this `authroutes` action attribute:

```
@if (Request::route()->getAction('authroutes', false))
    // this is one of the routes from `Route::auth`
@endif
```

`getAction` takes the property we want to find and a default value.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper function that will check auth routes.

```
function checkAuthRoute() {
 $routes = \Route::getRoutes();
 // iterate routes
 foreach($routes as $route){
   // your logic here
 }

}
```